# Does GCM works for android 2.3 platform?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I have created a APP using GCM which works correctly on Android platform 4.1 and 4.03 (I.e. Gets a RegId and register itself in my server and can even recieve a GCM), but when I start the emulator for android 2.3 (API 10) then the app gets installed but never registered I.E never gets RegId. When I start (install) the application for the first time then it receives a GCM message which I do not understand where it comes from but I can see that the device is not registered in my server. I also used a HTC phone with 2.3.3 android software and stil same result. Can any one see what the problem might be?

Comment: I've removed your salutation/signature (Regards, Farshid) from the post. Please don't include them in the future; your signature is already included by your user box. Thanks!~

Answer (score 2):

On the emulator it should normally not work, because it will not have a google account tied to the device. It is requiered for a device to have a google account and Google Play installed to register for an id.

The phone on the other hand should work.

Answer (score 1):

GCM will Work from Android 2.2.
Refer this tutorial it may help you,

http://androidv5.wordpress.com/2012/08/15/how-to-implement-google-cloud-messaging/

it works fine for me.

Comment: Yeah I saw that and I found the problem but the most intresting part was to get notification without initiating. Thanx

Comment: @Farshid Notification without initiating?