# Can I use GCM for a new application based on Android 2.2 FroYo?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

If possible give an example. Thank you.

Comment: See [Does GCM works for android 2.3 platform?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12346957/does-gcm-works-for-android-2-3-platform?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. GCM works since Android 2.2.

Example & docs: http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html