# How do I set up an Android project for GCM use where Android 2.2 is supported?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13129169/can-i-use-gcm-for-a-new-application-based-on-android-2-2-froyo), GCM is supported for Android 2.2. However when I add 
    `com.google.android.gms:play-services:4+` to my Gradle build file, I get a compilation error from Gradle stating:

```
Information:Gradle: [c:\path\AndroidManifest.xml:3,     C:\path\build\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services\4.3.23\AndroidManifest.xml:3] 
Main manifest has <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion='8'>    
but library uses minSdkVersion='9'
```

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a special Google Play Services version for Android 2.2 (Froyo). You should try it instead of the regular library.

[image: Google Play Services for Froyo]

Comment: Do you have any insight on whether or not Play services for froyo is added to the Maven repo? Ref  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21455328/play-services-for-froyo-not-to-be-found-on-gradle